# The system cannot find the path specified - But actually does

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a batch script that runs files from our file server, it works but I get errors in the command prompt that the says:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So what's causing this? The script can execute the file without any problems from for example:

```
\\fileserver01\SoftwareProgram\Setup.exe
```

It's just annoying to see that message when it actually works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us (the relevant part of) your batchfile.

Comment: What more relevant part of my batchfile do you want to see? I use for example this in my batchfile: `robocopy /S \\fileserver01\app\client_folder\ C:\client_folder\`

Comment: You first need to figure out which line of the batch file is generating that error.  To do this, leave echoing turned on.  (That is, wherever the batch file says "echo off" replace it with "echo on".)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the connection to the server is not stabil (like wifi) so the connection get sometimes interrupted. In the script with many accesses you notice this problems more then when u normal work on a server with one access per minute or something like this. So lets check your connection to the server etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping fileserver01 if no go then try FQDN fileserver01.domain.com or fileserver01.domain.local

If that works then try \fileserver01.domain.com\SoftwareProgram\Setup.exe

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try adding the whole domain of the fileserver and try that out if the error persists.